# Filtering react data table through mui modal

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

I am trying to create a react data table and filter the data in the table through mui textfield in a mui Modal.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er3iu.png) 
The filters in every column must open in the mui modal .Like this example [Like this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Y7C.png) They must have the functionality to search.
Kindly suggest me the code to filter every column separately through  mui text fields in the same Modal

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useTable, usePagination, useFilters, useGlobalFilter, useSortBy, useAsyncDebounce } from 'react-table'
import makeData from './makeData'
import MDBTypography from 'components/MDBTypography'
import { Divider, Grid, InputAdornment, Modal, Tooltip } from '@mui/material'
import ArrowDropUpOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowDropUpOutlined';
import ArrowDropDownOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowDropDownOutlined';
import SearchIcon from "assets/images/icons/svg/medium/SearchIcon.svg";
import { matchSorter } from 'match-sorter'
import MDBInput from 'components/MDBInput'
import MDBButton from 'components/MDBButton'
import FilterListOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FilterListOutlined';
import MDBCard from 'components/MDBCard'
const Styles = styled.div`
    padding: 1rem;
    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      border: 1px solid #44474A;
      tr {
        :last-child {
          td {
            border-bottom: 0;
          } 
        }

      }
      th{
        background:#1C1F21;
      }
      th,
      td {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #44474A;
        border-right: 1px solid #44474A;
        :last-child {
          border-right: 0;
        }
      }
    }
    .pagination {
      padding: 0.5rem;
    }
  `

// Define a default UI for filtering
function GlobalFilter({
  preGlobalFilteredRows,
  globalFilter,
  setGlobalFilter,
}) {
  const count = preGlobalFilteredRows.length
  const [value, setValue] = useState(globalFilter)
  const onChange = useAsyncDebounce(value => {
    setGlobalFilter(value || undefined)
  }, 200)
  // Set Filter popover
  const [mediaKits, setMediaKits] = useState([]);
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popover' : undefined;
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <MDBInput
        search={true}
        value={value || ""}
        fullWidth
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <MDBTypography component="img" src={SearchIcon} />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
        onChange={e => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
          onChange(e.target.value);
        }}
        placeholder={`Search ${count} records...`}
        variant="standard"
        width="400px"
      />

      <MDBButton
        size="medium"
        variant="contained"
        color="white"
        bgColor="smoke_light"
        fontWeight="medium"
        fontSize="md"
        borderSize="md"
        lineHeight="2xxl"
        aria-describedby={id}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <FilterListOutlinedIcon
          color="white"
        />
      </MDBButton>
      <Modal
        id={id}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <>

          <MDBCard bgcolor="black"  >
            {/* //sx={{ px: 0, pt:0, pb: 1.5, width:"min-content"}} */}
            <Grid sx={{ px: 2.5, py: 2 }}>
              <MDBTypography sx={{ pb: 1 }}>
                Filters
              </MDBTypography>
            </Grid>
            <Divider />
            <Tooltip title={`Search ${count} records...`}>
              <MDBInput
                sx={{ pr: 4, input: { cursor: 'pointer' } }}
                placeholder="Filter First Name..."
              />
            </Tooltip>
            <Divider />
            <Tooltip title={`Search ${count} records...`}>
              <MDBInput
                sx={{ pr: 4, input: { cursor: 'pointer' } }}
                placeholder="Filter Last Name..."
              />
            </Tooltip>
            <Divider />
            <Tooltip title={`Search ${count} records...`}>
              <filterGreaterThan />
            </Tooltip>
          </MDBCard>
        </>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
// Define a default UI for filtering
function DefaultColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, preFilteredRows, setFilter },
}) {
  const count = preFilteredRows.length

  return (
    <input
      value={filterValue || ''}
      onChange={e => {
        setFilter(e.target.value || undefined) // Set undefined to remove the filter entirely
      }}
      placeholder={`Search ${count} records...`}
    />
  )
}


// This is a custom filter UI for selecting
// a unique option from a list
function SelectColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, setFilter, preFilteredRows, id },
}) {
  // Calculate the options for filtering
  // using the preFilteredRows
  const options = React.useMemo(() => {
    const options = new Set()
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      options.add(row.values[id])
    })
    return [...options.values()]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  // Render a multi-select box
  return (
    <select
      value={filterValue}
      onChange={e => {
        setFilter(e.target.value || undefined)
      }}
    >
      <option value="">All</option>
      {options.map((option, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}

// This is a custom filter UI that uses a
// slider to set the filter value between a column's
// min and max values
function SliderColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, setFilter, preFilteredRows, id },
}) {
  // Calculate the min and max
  // using the preFilteredRows

  const [min, max] = React.useMemo(() => {
    let min = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    let max = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      min = Math.min(row.values[id], min)
      max = Math.max(row.values[id], max)
    })
    return [min, max]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="range"
        min={min}
        max={max}
        value={filterValue || min}
        onChange={e => {
          setFilter(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setFilter(undefined)}>Off</button>
    </>
  )
}

// This is a custom UI for our 'between' or number range
// filter. It uses two number boxes and filters rows to
// ones that have values between the two
function NumberRangeColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue = [], preFilteredRows, setFilter, id },
}) {
  const [min, max] = React.useMemo(() => {
    let min = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    let max = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      min = Math.min(row.values[id], min)
      max = Math.max(row.values[id], max)
    })
    return [min, max]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
      }}
    >
      <input
        value={filterValue[0] || ''}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => {
          const val = e.target.value
          setFilter((old = []) => [val ? parseInt(val, 10) : undefined, old[1]])
        }}
        placeholder={`Min (${min})`}
        style={{
          width: '70px',
          marginRight: '0.5rem',
        }}
      />
      to
      <input
        value={filterValue[1] || ''}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => {
          const val = e.target.value
          setFilter((old = []) => [old[0], val ? parseInt(val, 10) : undefined])
        }}
        placeholder={`Max (${max})`}
        style={{
          width: '70px',
          marginLeft: '0.5rem',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

function fuzzyTextFilterFn(rows, id, filterValue) {
  return matchSorter(rows, filterValue, { keys: [row => row.values[id]] })
}

// Let the table remove the filter if the string is empty
fuzzyTextFilterFn.autoRemove = val => !val

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  const filterTypes = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Add a new fuzzyTextFilterFn filter type.
      fuzzyText: fuzzyTextFilterFn,
      // Or, override the default text filter to use
      // "startWith"
      text: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
        return rows.filter(row => {
          const rowValue = row.values[id]
          return rowValue !== undefined
            ? String(rowValue)
              .toLowerCase()
              .startsWith(String(filterValue).toLowerCase())
            : true
        })
      },
    }),
    []
  )

  const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Let's set up our default Filter UI
      Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
    }),
    []
  )
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    visibleColumns,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setGlobalFilter,
    page, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
    // which has only the rows for the active page
    // The rest of these things are super handy, too ;)
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,

      data,
      defaultColumn, // Be sure to pass the defaultColumn option
      filterTypes,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0 },
    },
    useFilters, // useFilters!
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination,
  )

  // Render the UI for your table
  const firstPageRows = rows.slice(0, 20)
  return (
    <>
      {/* <pre>
          <code>
            {JSON.stringify(
              {
                pageIndex,
                pageSize,
                pageCount,
                canNextPage,
                canPreviousPage,
              },
              null,
              2
            )}
          </code>
        </pre> */}
      <GlobalFilter
        preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows}
        globalFilter={state.globalFilter}
        setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
      />
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} >
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                  {column.render('Header')}
                  {/* Add a sort direction indicator */}
                  <Grid
                    container
                    direction="row"
                    justifyContent='flex-end'
                    alignItems='flex-end'
                  >
                    <Grid
                      container
                      direction='row'
                      justifyContent="flex-end"
                      alignItems="flex-end"
                      sx={{ mt: -4.9, ml: 4 }}
                    >
                      {
                        column.isSorted ?
                          column.isSortedDesc
                            ? <ArrowDropUpOutlinedIcon color='white' sx={{ mb: 1 }} />
                            : <ArrowDropDownOutlinedIcon color='white' />
                          : ''
                      }
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return (<td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>)
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {/* 
          Pagination can be built however you'd like. 
          This is just a very basic UI implementation:
        */}
      <Grid
        container
        className="pagination"
        sx={{ ml: 42 }}
      >
        <Grid>
          <MDBTypography fontWeight="regular" fontSize="xxs" lineHeight='md' sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
            Page{' '}
            {/* <strong> */}
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length} |
            {/* </strong>{' '} */}
          </MDBTypography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid sx={{ ml: 1, mt: -0.4 }}>
          <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
            {'<<'}
          </button>{' '}
          <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
            {'<'}
          </button>{' '}
          <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
            {'>'}
          </button>{' '}
          <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
            {'>>'}
          </button>{' '}
        </Grid>
        {/* <span>
            | Go to page:{' '}
            <input
              type="number"
              defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
              onChange={e => {
                const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
                gotoPage(page)
              }}
              style={{ width: '100px' }}
            />
          </span>{' '}
          <select
            value={pageSize}
            onChange={e => {
              setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
            }}
          >
            {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
              <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                Show {pageSize}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select> */}
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}
function filterGreaterThan(rows, id, filterValue) {
  return rows.filter(row => {
    const rowValue = row.values[id]
    return rowValue >= filterValue
  })
}

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => {
    console.log('This is a test')
    setIsOpen(true);
  }
  const handleClose = () => setIsOpen(false);

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: <MDBTypography sx={{ mr: 2 }}>First Name</MDBTypography>,
        accessor: 'firstName',
      },
      {
        Header: <MDBTypography sx={{ mr: 2 }}>Last Name</MDBTypography>,
        accessor: 'lastName',
        filter: 'fuzzyText'
      },
      {
        Header: <MDBTypography sx={{ mr: 2 }}>Age</MDBTypography>,
        accessor: 'age',
        Filter: SliderColumnFilter,
        filter: 'equals'
      },
      {
        Header: <MDBTypography sx={{ mr: 2 }}>Visits</MDBTypography>,
        accessor: 'visits',
        filter: filterGreaterThan,
        Filter: NumberRangeColumnFilter,
        filter: 'between',
      },
      {
        Header: <MDBTypography sx={{ mr: 2 }}>Status</MDBTypography>,
        accessor: 'status',
        Filter: SelectColumnFilter,
        filter: 'includes',
      },
      {
        Header: <MDBTypography sx={{ mr: 2 }}>Profile Progress</MDBTypography>,
        accessor: 'progress',
        Filter: SliderColumnFilter,
        filter: filterGreaterThan,
      },
      {
        Header: <MDBTypography sx={{ mr: 2 }}>Edit</MDBTypography>,
        accessor: 'edit',

        Cell: ({ value }) => (
          <Grid
            container
            justifyContent="space-between">
            <MDBButton variant="outlined" onClick={() => handleEdit(value)}>Edit</MDBButton>
            <MDBButton variant="outlined" sx={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} onClick={handleOpen}>Delrte</MDBButton>
            <Modal
              // open={isOpen}
              // onClose={handleClose}
              aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
              aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
            >
              <MDBCard bgcolor="black"  >
                Are You Sure :
                <MDBButton>
                  Yes
                </MDBButton>
                <MDBButton onClick={handleClose}>
                  No
                </MDBButton>
              </MDBCard>
            </Modal>
          </Grid>
        )
      },
    ],
    []
  )

  function handleEdit(row) {
    console.log(row);
  }
  function HandleDelete(row) {
    console.log(row)
    setIsOpen(true)
    console.log("Set is open done")
  }

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(100).map((item) => ({ ...item, edit: item })))
  return (
    <Styles>
      <MDBTypography fontWeight="regular" fontSize="xxs" lineHeight='md'>
        <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
      </MDBTypography>
    </Styles>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Check this one: https://v4.mui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/